# i want to get data from attribute data-post

Tags: magento2, jquery

```
<a href="#" class="action towishlist btn-round pink" title="Add to Wish List" aria-label="Add to Wish List" data-post="{&quot;action&quot;:&quot;https:\/\/abc.test\/en\/wishlist\/index\/add\/&quot;,&quot;data&quot;:{&quot;product&quot;:3311,&quot;uenc&quot;:&quot;aHR0cHM6Ly9nYW1lby50ZXN0L2VuL3BsYXlzdGF0aW9uLmh0bWw,&quot;}}" data-action="add-to-wishlist" role="button" date-ref="3311">
        <i class="fal fa-heart fill-linear-gradient-pink-purple-light"></i>
</a>
```

i want to get data from data post attribute in Jquery knock out js how i can get this ?

Answer (score 0):

You can use something like this,

```
const postData = $('.action.towishlist.btn-round.pink').data('post')
```

[image]